# Problem in my API REST with CRUD (delete and update), i use nodejs, express, javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, express

I want to create an api with a json database (with several tables so several json) and make my controllers link with my different routes.
In my POSTMAN tests, get and put work, but update and delete do not work.

*Can you help me please?*

**my files :**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpSok.png)

**my controllers :**

```js
function updatePost(filename, filepath, id, newPost) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        helper.mustBeInArray(filename, id)
        .then(post => {
            const index = filename.findIndex(p => p.id == post.id)
            id = { id: post.id }
            filename[index] = { ...id, ...newPost }
            helper.writeJSONFile(filepath, filename)
            resolve(filename[index])
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
}

function deletePost(filename, filepath, id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        helper.mustBeInArray(filename, id)
        .then(() => {
            posts = filename.filter(p => p.id !== id)
            helper.writeJSONFile(filepath, filename)
            resolve()
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
}
```

**And here my example for one route for one table :**

```js
/* Update a postPerson */
router.put('/:id', m.mustBeInteger, m.checkFieldsPostPerson, async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id    
    
    await postModel.updatePost(postsPerson, pathPerson, id, req.body)
    .then(postModel => res.json({
        message: `The postPerson #${id} has been updated`,
        content: postModel
    }))
    .catch(err => {
        if (err.status) {
            res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message })
        }
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
    })
})

/* Delete a postPerson */
router.delete('/:id', m.mustBeInteger, async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    
    await postModel.deletePost(postsPerson, pathPerson, id)
    .then(postModel => res.json({
        message: `The postPerson #${id} has been deleted`
    }))
    .catch(err => {
        if (err.status) {
            res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message })
        }
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
    })
})
```

**And that , this is my code for route GET and POST , that work for them :**

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await postModel.getPosts(postsPerson)
    .then(postsPerson => res.json(postsPerson))
    .catch(err => {
        if (err.status) {
            res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message })
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
        }
    })
})


router.get('/:id', m.mustBeInteger, async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id    
    
    await postModel.getPost(postsPerson, id)
    .then(postModel => res.json(postModel))
    .catch(err => {
        if (err.status) {
            res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message })
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
        }
    })
})

/* Insert a new postPerson */
router.post('/', m.checkFieldsPostPerson, async (req, res) => {
    await postModel.insertPost(postsPerson, pathPerson, req.body)
    .then(postModel => res.status(201).json({
        message: `The postPerson #${postModel.id} has been created`,
        content: postModel
    }))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ message: err.message }))
})
```

**And POSTMAN say that for delete and put:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot DELETE /portfolio/person</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot PUT /portfolio/person</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: As per error message, you are trying to access `/portfolio/person`. But your delete route also requires a param `id`. I'm not sure without seeing the complete integration, but your route should include the param, for eg something like `/portfolio/person/1`

Comment: And please don't mix `await` and `then/catch`. Either use one or another. I'd prefer `await`. `const result = await postModel.getPost(postsPerson, id); res.json(result)`

Comment: @Vipulw thank it's working for PUT !!! but delete , postman say : {
    "message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../data/person.json'"
}, and he does'nt delete him , but thank you for the PUT help !!

Comment: @Anatoly thank you i take the advice !!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).